# Can one reset a qubit to the ground state on real IBM quantum processor?

Tags: qiskit, programming

As explained [here](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2021/02/quantum-mid-circuit-measurement/), IBM provided the possibility to reset a qubit to the ground state within the Qiskit framework.

However it is not clear whether this tool is available for any backend or it works only on simulators.

Can I reset a real qubit on Qiskit?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as pointed out by this tutorial here: **[Mid-Circuit Measurements Tutorial](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/systems/midcircuit-measurement/#Mid-Circuit-Measurements-Tutorial)**

In particular they showed an example of single qubit reset on `ibmq_manhattan`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As [@KAJ226](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/9858/kaj226) said in his answer, some of IBM quantum systems support Reset operation.

You can check whether some backend supports Reset as follows:

```
config = backend.configuration()
print('reset' in config.supported_instructions)
```

And to get a list of all the backends that support Reset:

```
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub = 'ibm-q')

backends_support_reset = provider.backends(filters = lambda x: not x.configuration().simulator
    and 'reset' in x.configuration().supported_instructions)

print(backends_support_reset)
```

Comment: May you share the current state of such a list? Because at the moment I have no access to processors with more than 7 qubits. I applied for more computational resource but in the waiting it would be helpful to know if this is gonna block my schedule.

Comment: I have no access to processors with more than 5 qubits. You ask this question on Qiskit's [Slack channel](https://qiskit.slack.com).